# A boy and his war machine

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, robots, childrens-novel

A juvenile SF novel from the early 80s, maybe? A non-conformist boy is sent off to an authoritarian school in the middle of nowhere, but forms a partnership with a war robot prototype - there's a scene where the robot is on display at a sports arena and proceeds to smash cars (?), the title is "Ogre" or something similar. Definitely NOT "The Iron Giant".

Comment: Do you remember what the cover looked like?  (Note ISFDb doesn't list any works from that time period with "Ogre" in the title that seem to fit.)

Comment: Obligatory mention that the *Bolo* series [was turned into the OGRE boardgames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogre_(board_game)) due to licensing issues.

Comment: Could the title have been _Rogue_ or _Golem_, both of which are kind of similar to _Ogre_? Although ISFDB doesn't list any likely looking novels with these titles around 1980.

Comment: Partial match to *Ricky Ricotta's Mighty Robot* series (2000-2016) by Dav Pilkey - it's a boy mouse who befriends a robot who was designed to destroy the world by a mad scientist rat. Performs rescues of the world from a range of aliens from the other planets in our solar system

Comment: I think the cover was mainly black, with maybe a semi-abstract picture of the war robot? The reason I'm thinking "OGRE" is I was/am a big fan of the game, and it might have inspired me to pick the book up. The obnoxious thing is I'm pretty sure if I saw the cover I'd recognize it right away,